# How to sort the result with multiple conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to build a database to store surveys,  questions, answers
so I can dynamically generate surveys, capture answers and report out of them.

**Question**
How to sort the results in the following order?
Order by *surveys_questions.sort* however, if parent id is > 0 then I need to bring all of the children under it and sort the children by *surveys_controls.sort*.

I have 5 tables:

1. surveys table to hold the name of each survey (Family income survey)
2. "questions" table to store all the questions with in the survey. Please note the parent_id column. this once will be used when I want to have sub questions
3. a table to store the available tools ex. text box, radio button, checkbox....
4. "Answers" table
5. a table to store the relationship between the question and the associated tools. so for example question 1 will have tools id 1 (radio button) and it is selected by default...

now the issue that I am having is that I am not able to sort the result or answers correctly.

**You can find my code and run queries on this link**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ee97/1

**NOTE: I have created a smalled version of the problem on this link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9f6e3/4

if someone can help he with this problem then I will use the same solution to solve the actual problem.**

Comment: There's quiet a bit of code here. Maybe you can make a Fiddler http://sqlfiddle.com/ and insert some working values to the tables?

Comment: It is not working for me as max charecters is 8000 Your schema ddl is too large (more than 8000 characters). Please submit a smaller DDL.

Comment: @Gimmy here you go http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ee97/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your ORDER BY line:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN q.parent_id = 0 THEN q.question_id WHEN q.parent_id !=0 THEN q.parent_id = 0 END ASC, q.sort, t.sort
```

Here is the **[Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ee97/12)**

Comment: Thank you. This answer worked also this worked          ORDER BY CASE WHEN q.parent_id = 0 THEN q.question_id ELSE q.parent_id END ASC, q.question_id, q.sort, t.sort